# Coolant and How much

Tags: chevrolet, coolant, spark

I was wondering how much coolant my 2014 Chevy Spark LS needs. I have one gallon in my garage but is that enough.

Comment: Check the type of coolant you have make sure it is the correct color. Coolant is sold in 2 concentrations. Some is premixed with water in a 50/50 ratio. You add it right from the jug. The other variety requires you to mix it with water. The advantage of the premix is that the water is of known good quality and the ratio will be correct.

Answer (score 1):

It has 5 US quarts coolant.

You can check [HERE](https://www.automobile-catalog.com/oil_coolant_capacity/2014/1777385/chevrolet_spark_1_0_lt.html) as a reference